# VSTS "Deploy Compose Application to Service Fabric" to an agent with SF SDK 2.8 or 3.0 fails

Tags: azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I use ***Deploy Compose Application to Service Fabric*** to deploy containers with VSTS on Service Fabric . My build agent had Service Fabric SDK 2.7. As soon as I upgrade it to 2.8 or 3.0, the VSTS task breaks with

> The ServiceDnsName for DefaultService 'xxx' is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned [vsts-tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks), debugged ***ServiceFabricCompose*** and found out that UI parameter *Application Name* is placed into *New-ServiceFabricComposeDeployment -DeploymentName*.

For old SDK 2.7 we had "fabric:/XYZ" in *Application Name*.

This format is not valid for SDK 2.8 + 3.0.

Changing to *Application Name* to "XYZ" solved the problem.